# How can I get all the raw contacts for a contact with a specific LOOKUP_KEY?

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-cursor

Given a phone number, I first find out the LOOKUP_KEY of the Contact that has this number. From there, is there a way to retrieve the list of raw contacts with a single query?

I tried the following approach

```
ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
        // Get all RawContacts associated with lookupKey
        Cursor contactCursor = cr.query(
                Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, lookup_key),
                new String[]{ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID},
                null,
                null,
                null);
```

But contactCursor always contains a single entry, even when the queried contract has multiple raw contacts. 
To be honest, I do not understand very well why the query above even returns anything, since there is no RawContacts entry in the table ContactsContract.Contacts. I guess that it just returns the _ID entry of this table, which is the Contact_ID (not the Id of a RawContact).

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `LOOKUP_KEY` in this scenario, instead get the `Contacts._ID` from the phone number, and then get all `RawContacts` by [`CONTACT_ID`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContactsColumns.html#CONTACT_ID):

```
cr.query(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
    new String[]{ RawContacts._ID },
    RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + "=" + theContactId,
    null,
    null);
```

Comment: Thanks marmor. Since the starting point is the phone number, is it OK to just get theContactId directly via PhoneLookup query instead of the Lookup_Key? , this would save me one query (to resolve theContactId from Lookup_Key).

Comment: yep, exactly what I meant: phone number > contact-id > raw-contacts